# Refer the document which is currently being updated

Tags: arangodb

I know that it is possible to do it this way:

```
FOR user IN users
FILTER user._key == "7"
UPDATE user WITH { friends: PUSH(user.friends, "8") } IN users
```

But it is a little verbose. I wonder if there is a way to do something like this:

```
UPDATE "7" WITH { friends: PUSH(CURRENT.friends, "8") } IN users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right; there currently is no easy way to address the `CURRENT` document when only updating one item.

One could use the [DOCUMENT function](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/MiscellaneousFunctions.html#miscellaneous_functions) to fetch the original document again:

```
UPDATE "7" WITH 
  { friends: PUSH(DOCUMENT("user/7").friends, "8") } IN users
```

However, it would fetch the document twice and thus be less efficient than your first query.

Your can use `db._explain()` to revalidate that your first query will be a single index access.

[I've added a feature request to track this.](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1792)

To be more persistant with the `RETURN` syntax (if) that variable will be named `OLD`.